# Multiple onClick fuctions for Calculator?

Tags: java, android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhPkq.jpg

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int c,d;
    float x,y,z,a;
    EditText ed1,ed2;
    TextView t1;
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4;

    public void add(View v){

       ed1 =  findViewById(R.id.editText);

       ed2 =  findViewById(R.id.editText2);

       t1  =  findViewById(R.id.textView);

       b1    =  findViewById(R.id.button);
       b2    =  findViewById(R.id.button2);
       b3    =  findViewById(R.id.button3);
       b4    =  findViewById(R.id.button4);


       c = Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());

       d = Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());

       x = c + d;

       t1.setText(String.valueOf(x));
    }
    public void sub(View v){

        y = c-d;
        t1.setText(String.valueOf(y));
    }
    public void mul(View v){

        z = c*d;
        t1.setText(String.valueOf(z));
    }
    public void div(View v){

        a = c/d;
        t1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Getting App Crash when clicking on Subtract(sub), Multiply, Divide.

But if I do addition first and then click any other functions it will work fine, it is just when first time clicking on the buttons. Check Image.

Comment: Move the `findViewById` lines from `add` method to `onCreate`.

Comment: As Rashin mentioned, some buttons are null cause they have not assigned by `findViewById(id)`, which you must do after activity view created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your views in the `add` method. You should do that in the `onCreate` method. 
This is why it is working if you click on the add button first.

```java
public void add(View v){
   c = Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
   d = Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());
   x = c + d;
   t1.setText(String.valueOf(x));
}
```

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    t1 = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    b1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
}
```

Edit:
You are fetching the values from the EditText's only in the `add` method. You should add the following two lines for the remaining operations:

```java
c = Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
d = Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Added my views to onCreate and kept c & d to add method. Still nothing it is not crashing but it is showing answer 0 in all cased except add. And again after executing add all other methods works fine

Comment: Nice! Thanks is there any optimal way of doing this?

Comment: It's a matter of taste. Your actual solution is completely fine. Another option would be to make your Activity implement `View.OnClickListener` and handle every action from one method. It would remove the duplication and for this use-case I think it's acceptable too.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you will get crash(`NullPointerException` because of `null object reference` `t1` is not referencing yet so you must call `add()` in `onCreate` method

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add()
}
```

Comment: Can't do that this shows up: add(View)in MainActivity cannot be applied to () @Ugas

Comment: As I think `View` in `add()` is useless so you can remove the parameter